# Algorithm step question.

Tags: algorithms

**From Peter Smith's book on Godel, p. 23.  For input n, algorithm P is run with input i for j steps, where i and j are obtained from n by the inversion of Cantor's pairing function. Taking n as 3, for example, we get i=2, j=0.  How does one interpret this, since it makes no sense to think of 0 steps?
I appreciate all help.  am**

Answer (score 1):

If we apply an algorithm for $0$ steps, this is generally interpreted as "don't do anything." This is analogous to applying a function zero time, were $f(x)=x^2$ applies zero times to $7$ yields $7$.

Comment: Thanks.  In other words when we come to n=3, we simply go on to n = 4?

Comment: @agapito probably, but I would need more context to the problem to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Stella.  It's part of proof of theorem that states that if a set is the numerical domain of some algorithm then it is effectively enumerable, in Smith's book.